# Javascript hide after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I use this code to show a form after a link is clicked:

```
$(function () {
    $('.msg').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.msgarea').show();
    });
});

<a href="" class="msg" id="55"> Reply </a>
<form class="msgarea">
    <input />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

.msgarea{ display:none; }
```

Now I need the link "msg" to disappear, what would the code look like? I'm totally new in js

UPDATE:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $('.msg').on('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).next('.msgarea').show();
       $(this).hide();
        });
        </script>

<a href="" class="msg" id="55"> Reply </a>
        <form class="msgarea">
        <input />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>

.msgarea{ display:none; }
```

Comment: google for dom manipulation using javascript or jquery.

Comment: $(this).hide() for example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem in saying `hide` like after `show` the form like bellow

```
$('.msg').on('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).next('.msgarea').show();
       $(this).hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/29/)

Comment: Is it because of <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js'></script> ? Because I need it for another function

Comment: @user3838972 did you see my demo

Comment: Now I see whats wrong: $(function()
        { need also to be there ^^ thanks